# Program used external function 'llvm.returnaddress.i8' which could not be resolved

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to use `llvm.returnaddress.i8` in a pass for getting return value of a function.

After I execute `../llvm/bin/lli test_re.bc`, I get

> LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'llvm.returnaddress.i8' which could not be resolved!

I don't know how to solve it. Is there any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question with sufficient and specific information, such sample code, to describe your problem and the effort you attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intrinsic is called [llvm.returnaddress](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-returnaddress-intrinsic), not `llvm.returnaddress.i8`.

```llvm
declare i8* @llvm.returnaddress(i32)
declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

@fmt = constant [20 x i8] c"Return address: %p\0a\00"

define i32 @main() {
  %fmt = getelementptr [20 x i8], [20 x i8]* @fmt, i32 0, i32 0
  %ra = call i8* @llvm.returnaddress(i32 0)
  call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* %fmt, i8* %ra)
  ret i32 0
}
```